# SOLR PHP MYSQL Integration

Tags: php, mysql, solr, indexing, lucene

I'm newbie to Solr and I am trying to integrate it with Mysql and PHP.
I got the Solr server running and I have configured the db schema as well. But when I ty to access `collection1 -> data import`, I get the following error:

```
sorry, no dataimport-handler defined!
```

I searched a lot on google but I'm still confused:

- How to make solr work on my php web application.
- How exactly it would work?

And here is my data-config.xml file,

```
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
 url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:81/solr" user="root" password=""
 batchSize="1" />
           <document name="products">
           <entity name="products_data" query="SELECT * FROM products">
            <field column="product_id" name="product_id" />
            <field column="product_name" name="product_name" />     
            <field column="product_description" name="product_description" />
            <field column="product_price" name="product_price" />
           </entity>
          </document>
   </dataConfig>
```

Comment: -1 Please post a part of your code and be more specific on what did you try until now. You saying that you have tried to access the data, what code did you exactly use?

Comment: I've added my data-config.xml snippet.

Comment: It is not enough for solr to define a datasource. You need to use it somewhere. You need a special type of request handler, named dataimport-handler. Those need to be declared in your solrconfig.xml. I assume you have not done anything to the solrconfig.xml? If else, please post it ...

Answer (score 1):

The message is Solr complaining about the fact that there is no `requestHandler` defined that is of the type `solr.DataImportHandler`.

You can find an example definition of such a handler in `example/example-DIH/solr/db/conf` in the distribution.

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="solr.DataImportHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="config">db-data-config.xml</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

You'll have to update it to match the configuration file name that you've saved yourself, and make sure it's placed in the `conf` directory.

There should also be an error logged to the general log for Solr, as long as you've [followed the steps in the wiki for setting up logging](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrLogging).